# What does the universal gas constant, $R ,$ represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, physical-constants

What does universal gas constant represent?

My textbook says:

> it is the energy required to raise a ideal gas by 1K

The Mayer formula is

$$
C_{\text{p}} = C_{\text{v}}+R
\,,$$
so isn't text book definition is wrong as it is ignoring the factor $C_{\text{v}} ?$

Comment: Your book really doesn't say that, does it?  That can't be an exact quote.  If your book says that, get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) tells us that for a system in thermal equilibrium each degree of freedom of a system has an energy of $\tfrac{1}{2}k_BT$, where the constant $k_B$ is [Boltzmann's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant). So for example an ideal gas has just the three translational degrees of freedom and the average energy per particle will be $\tfrac{3}{2}k_BT$.

If we consider a mole of the gas this contains $N_A$ particles, where $N_A$ is the [Avagadro constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), so the average energy per mole is:

$$ U = \tfrac{3}{2}N_Ak_BT = \tfrac{3}{2}RT \tag{1} $$

where $R = N_Ak_B$ is the ideal gas constant. So the ideal gas constant is simply the Boltzmann constant times the number of particles in a mole. You can argue about whether $R$ or $k_B$ is the more fundamental constant. My position is that Boltzmann's constant is the more fundamental since the numerical value of $R$ depends on a somewhat arbitrary choice of how many particles there are in a mole.

You are quite correct that $R$ is not the energy required to raise the temperature of an ideal gas by $1$K. As equation (1) shows the energy required to raise the temperature by $1$K at constant volume is $\tfrac{3}{2}R$. However I don't think this is a good way to understand what $R$ means. It is far better to link it back to the equipartition theorem as I have done above.